# return the output of `getSymbols()` as a data frame

Tags: r, readline, xts, zoo, quantmod

If i try to take input from user and save the data frame into another for further use in code

```
 comp.name <- readline(prompt = "Enter the company name: ")
 getSymbols(comp.name , src = "yahoo", verbose = TRUE, from = "2018-03-01")
 tyu2 <- as.data.frame(comp.name)
```

I don't get the data back, but only a data frame with a single factor value. Please suggest something. The further code goes like

```
tyu <- tyu2$(comp.name).Open
x <- row.names(tyu2)
final <- length(tyu)
final <- as.numeric(final)
p <- ggplot(data = tyu2 , aes(x= x ,y=tyu))+geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
p
```

It may be a foolish mistake. I am quite new to R. Thanks.

Comment: try `tyu2 <- as.data.frame(comp.name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: yes, it converts it into a data base but the data base i want to access is still as a character inside the tyu2 data base due to the readline prompt. Is there any way i can convert that character class back onto xts zoo class?

Comment: could you please help me out @rosscova

Comment: Do you mean you want the output of `getSymbols` to be put into the data frame? I don't know what that function does, but maybe try changing that line to `comp.name <- getSymbols(comp.name...`?

Comment: get symbol just downloads the data related to the company i enter into rstudio. like if i want stock details of a particular company without needing to download the csv file i can use getSymbols to download directly into the rstudio

Comment: You need to edit your question; you do not want `factor` class, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` avoids this. But it seems you don't want `character` class either. What class DO you want?

Comment: @Shique is right, your question title does not accurately describe your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getSymbols` auto assigns the returned value to the global environment by default, meaning you'll get an object with the same name as the company you queried. To stop that behaviour, set `auto.assign` to `FALSE`. This way, you can assign the returned values to an object yourself:

```
comp.name <- readline(prompt = "Enter the company name: ")
tyu2 <- getSymbols(comp.name ,
                   src = "yahoo",
                   verbose = TRUE,
                   from = "2018-03-01",
                   auto.assign = FALSE)
tyu2 <- as.data.frame(tyu2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: It works as well by using `tyu2 <- as.data.frame(get(comp.name))` without the `auto.assign`. But +1 for finding that out

Comment: Good point @Shique, I knew there was a way to do that, but couldn't think of it. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent character-vectors to be converted to factor in the creation of a data.frame, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the data.frame.

```
 tyu2 <- as.data.frame(comp.name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @Shique beat you to it by about 40s :)

Comment: @rosscova i really have to learn how to type using all ten fingers ;-)

Comment: @Shique if you convert your comment to an answer, i will delete this one...

Comment: yes, it converts it into a data base but the data base i want to access is still as a character inside the tyu2 data base due to the readline prompt. Is there any way i can convert that character class back onto xts zoo class?

Comment: @Wimpel my comment does not seem to be the solution as rahul yadav does not want `character` class but `xts zoo` class